# Question on a closed-form expression related to the harmonic number $H_n$

Tags: number-theory, closed-form, gamma-function, riemann-zeta, harmonic-numbers

In this question the notation $\tilde{f}(x)$ refers to an analytic representation of the summatory function

$$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x a(n)\tag{1}$$

that converges to

$$\underset{\epsilon\to 0}{\text{lim}}\left(\frac{f(x-\epsilon)+f(x+\epsilon)}{2}\right)\tag{2}$$

whereas the notation $\hat{f}(x)$ refers to a closed form expression for $\tilde{f}(x)$ which is undefined at the discontinuities of $f(x)$.

---

Consider the following three summatory functions

---

$$h(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}\tag{3}$$

$$s(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x 1\tag{4}$$

$$g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^x n\tag{5}$$

---

and their corresponding analytic representations

---

$$\tilde{h}(x)=\log(x)+\gamma+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K (\text{Ei}(2 \pi i k x)+\text{Ei}(-2 \pi i k x))\right),\quad x>0\tag{6}$$

$$\tilde{s}(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^K \frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)}{\pi k}\right),\quad x>0\tag{7}$$

$$\tilde{g}(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{12}+\underset{K\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^K \frac{2 \pi k x \sin(2 \pi k x)+\cos(2 \pi k x)}{2 \pi^2 k^2}\right),\quad x\ge 0\tag{8}$$

---

Whereas formulas (6) and (7) above are both only valid for $x>0$, formula (8) above is valid for $x\ge 0$ and converges to an even function of $x$.

---

The primary objective of this question is to find a closed form expression for $\hat{h}(x)$ analogous to the closed form expressions for $\hat{s}(x)$ and $\hat{g}(x)$ defined below.

$$\hat{s}(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i \left(\log\left(1-e^{2 i \pi x}\right)-\log\left(1-e^{-2 i \pi x}\right)\right)}{2 \pi}\tag{9}$$

$$\hat{g}(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-2 i \pi x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{2 i \pi x}\right)+2 i \pi x \left(\log\left(1-e^{2 i \pi x}\right)-\log\left(1-e^{-2 i \pi  x}\right)\right)}{4 \pi^2}\tag{10}$$

---

**Question**: Is there a closed-form expression for

$$f_1(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\text{Ei}(i k x)+\text{Ei}(-i k x))\,,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{11}$$

where $\text{Ei}(z)$ is the [exponential integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html) analogous to the closed form representations defined in formulas (12) and (13) below?

$$f_2(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(k x)}{\pi k}=\frac{i}{2 \pi} \left(\log\left(1-e^{i x}\right)-\log\left(1-e^{-i x}\right)\right)\tag{12}$$

$$f_3(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k x \sin(k x)+\cos(k x)}{2 \pi^2 k^2}=\frac{\text{Li}_2\left(e^{-i x}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(e^{i x}\right)+i x \left(\log \left(1-e^{i x}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-i x}\right)\right)}{4 \pi ^2}\tag{13}$$

---

The related Laplace transform

$$F_1(s)=s\, \mathcal{L}_x[f_1(x)](s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f_1(x)\,e^{-s x}\,dx=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \log\left(1+\frac{s^2}{k^2}\right)\tag{14}$$

has the closed form representation

$$F_1(s)=-\log\left(\frac{\sinh(\pi s)}{\pi s}\right)\tag{15}$$

which is based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4447898) to one of my related questions.

---

Mathematica doesn't seem to be capable of simplifying the sum in formula (11) above or deriving the inverse Laplace transform of $\log\left(\frac{\sinh(\pi s)}{\pi s}\right) \frac{1}{s}$ related to formula (15) above.

---

With respect to my question, the best I've been able to do so far is a finite sum where the number of terms are dependent on the magnitude of $x$, but that's not the objective solution. I suspect there's a closed form expression for $f_1(x)$ that's more analogous in complexity to formula (13) above than the simpler formula (12) above.

---

The function $f_1(x)$ defined in formula (11) above can also be expressed in terms of the exponential integral function $E_1(z)$ as

$$f_1(x)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (E_1(i k x)+E_1(-i k x))\,,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{16}$$

or in terms of the ["upper" incomplete gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html)  $\Gamma(0,z)$ as

$$f_1(x)=-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (\Gamma (0,i k x)+\Gamma (0,-i k x))\,,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{17}$$

or assuming $x\ge 0$, in terms of the [cosine integral function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CosineIntegral.html) $\text{Ci}(x)$ as

$$f_1(x)=2\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \text{Ci}(k\,x)\,,\quad x\ge 0\,.\tag{18}$$

---

I'm looking for a result for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ which is useful in the evaluation of other related formulas under investigation, but I suppose a result for $x\ge 0$ is better than nothing.

---

Figure (1) below illustrates the function $(\text{Ei}(i x)+\text{Ei}(-i x))$, related to the term of formula (11) above for $f_1(x)$, has a branch point at $x=0$, is an even function of $x$ with a decaying oscillation around the real axis as $|x|\to\infty$, and $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}(\text{Ei}(i x)+\text{Ei}(-i x))=0$.

[image: Illustration of (Ei(i x)+Ei(-i x))]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $(\text{Ei}(i x)+\text{Ei}(-i x))$

---

Figure (2) below illustrates the function $\text{Ci}(x)$, related to the term of formula (18) above for $f_1(x)$, has an undesirable branch cut along the negative real axis.

[image: Illustration of $Im(Ci(x))]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of $\Im(\text{Ci}(x))$

---

Figure (3) below illustrates formula (6) for $\tilde{h}(x)$ above in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $h(x)$ defined in formula (3) above where formula (6) is evaluated at $K=20$. The red discrete evaluation points in Figure (3) below illustrate the evaluation of formula (6) for $\tilde{h}(x)$ at integer values of $x$.

---

[image: Illustration of formula (6) for}h(x)]

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of formula (6) for $\tilde{h}(x)$

---

Formulas (11), (12), and (13) above lead to the following formulas for $\zeta(s+1)$, $\zeta(s)$, and $\zeta(s-1)$.

---

$$\zeta(s+1)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[f_1(2 \pi x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f_1(2 \pi x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx$$ $$=2^{s+1}\, \pi^s\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\, \Gamma(-s)\, \underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n^s\right),\quad\Re(s)<-1\tag{19}$$

---

$$\zeta(s)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[f_2(2 \pi x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f_2(2 \pi x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx$$ $$=2^s \pi^{s-1} \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma (1-s) \underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N n^{s-1}\right),\quad\Re(s)<0\tag{20}$$

---

$$\zeta(s-1)=s\, \mathcal{M}_x[f_3(2 \pi x)](-s)=s \int\limits_0^\infty f_3(2 \pi x)\,x^{-s-1}\,dx$$ $$=-2^{s-1} \pi^{s-2} \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right) \Gamma(2-s) \sum\limits_{n=1}^N n^{s-2},\quad\Re(s)<1\tag{21}$$

Comment: ComplexYetTrivial gave a closed form in a comment in the answer to this [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222589/on-mathrm-sum-limits-x-1-infty-cix)

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks, but that closed form isn't useful to me as it's analogous to the derivation of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)}{k}=\pi \left(\lfloor x\rfloor -x+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ from $\lfloor x\rfloor =x-\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin (2 \pi k x)}{k}\right)$ whereas what I'm looking for is analogous to $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin(2 \pi k x)}{k}=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\log \left(1-e^{2 i \pi  x}\right)-\log \left(1-e^{-2 i \pi  x}\right)\right)$.

Comment: Also posted to MathOverflow, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440928/closed-form-of-a-sum-related-to-analytic-representations-of-hx-sum-n-1x